# Mongodb : How to find documents in which fields match an ObjectId or a string?

Tags: mongodb

I have some documents in a collection in Mongodb :

```
{_id : ObjectId('533af69b923967ac1801e113'), fKey : '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478', ... }
{_id : ObjectId('5343bd1e2305566008434afc'), fKey : ObjectId('5343bd1e2305566008434afc'), ...} }
```

As you can see my field *fkey* can be set by a *string* or an *ObjectId*.

I would like to get all documents which match '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478' or ObjectId('5343bd1e2305566008434afc').

But if i run :

```
db.mycollection.find({fkey : '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478'})
```

I only get the first document of the collection.

**Is there a way to configure Mongodb in order to get all documents which match the request without checking the type ?**

Thanks for your help.

Pierre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options for you here.

You could use mongo's [`$or` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
db.mycollection.find({ 
  $or: [ 
    { fKey: '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478' }, 
    { fKey: ObjectId( '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478' ) } 
  ] 
})
```

> The `$or` operator performs a logical `OR` operation on an array of two or more `<expressions>` and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the `<expressions>`.

---

You could also use the [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
db.mycollection.find({ 
  fKey: { 
    "$in": [ '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478', ObjectId( '533aeb09ebef89282c6cc478' )  ] 
  }
})
```

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

---

It sounds to me like these inconsistencies are not meant to be there. I recommend going through your code and data pipelines and figure out who/what is inserting the `fKey` value with an unknown datatype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you about data consistency.
For easier requesting, i would have like Mongodb to find without checking fields type by adding an option in the request or something like that..